# Let $H$ Hilbert, why is the set $X$ not equal to the set $\mathcal{C}^2(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $H$ Hilbert space and consider the  set $X$ defined by
$X=\left\{\varphi \in C^{1}(H ; \mathbf{R}) ; D \varphi\right.$ is Lipschitz on bounded sets of $H$ for all $h, k \in H, \lim _{t \rightarrow 0^{+}}(1 / t)(D \varphi(x+t k)-D \varphi(x), h)$ exists and is uniformly continuous on bounded sets of $H\}$.

Now P.L. Lions in [Viscosity solutions of fully nonlinear second-order equations and optimal stochastic control in infinite dimensions. Part I: the case of
bounded stochastic evolutions] says that if $H=\mathbb{R}^n$  then $X=\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and of course this is true since the characterizing condition of $X$ is equivalent to the existence and locally continuity of the partial derivatives.

Then the author claims that if $H$ is a general Hilbert space this is not true anymore. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous function on ${\mathbb R}^n$ is uniformly continuous on bounded sets, since their closure is compact. This no longer applies in general Hilbert space, as closed bounded sets of Hilbert space need not be compact.

Comment: yes but here he talks about bounded subsets not bounded and closed subsets. Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify.